# iOS - go to a page with if condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, segue

I want to go to other page after user **insert correct username and correct password**. How to do that ? 
First menu is *ViewController*. Second view is *Utama*. Username is gotten from *username NSString* and password is gotten from *password NSString*.

**The correct username is "Andika" and the correct password is 1234.**

Storyboard
[image]

ViewController.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *appTittle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordTextField;
- (IBAction)okPressed:(id)sender;
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    }

    - (IBAction)okPressed:(id)sender {

        NSString *username = [_usernameTextField text];
        NSString *password = [_passwordTextField text];

        if([username compare:@"andika"] && [password compare:@"1234"]) {
                //????
        }

    }
@end
```

Utama.m

```
#import "Utama.h"

@interface Utama ()

@end

@implementation Utama

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

UPDATED : I'm sorry, I'm newbie. I still can't go to another page.

I give identifier like this
[image]

This is modified code in ViewController.m
[image]

Comment: if compare to strings you should use this method isEqualToString:

Comment: ok, thanks for important information

Answer (score 2):

You can instantiate the `Utama` like this.

```
Utama *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"nameOfStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Utama"];
```

If `ViewController` is on `UINavigationController`, you can use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES]
```

However if the `ViewController` is a rootViewController of window, you can set the `vc` as a `rootViewController`.

```
[window setRootViewController:vc];
```

Make sure that the `window` is the instance of your app's key window.

Comment: still can't go to another page. You can see my updated information in my question

Comment: this answer is a good one. IMO, using navigation controller is better than using segue, especially for newbie. In order to make this works, you have to use `UINavigationController` and set your `ViewController` root view controller of it.

Comment: I get error when I add "[window setRootViewController:vc];". It's said that window isn't identified.

Comment: @andika_kurniawan try `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keywindow]` instead of window. I don't recommend to use `keywindow` but it works. Make sure that the `keywindow` doesn't mean the application's main window.

Answer (score 1):

**Utama** is a uitabbarcontroller right!? If you want to go to zeroth tab on clicking ok, give an identifier like "**DummyTab**" to the Utama view and use below code:

```
UITabBarController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DummyTab"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller setSelectedIndex:0];
```

Comment: still can't go to another page. You can see my updated information in my question

Comment: Did u try using isEqualtoString instead of compare!?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet to solve you're problem:

```
   Utama *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Utama"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: still can't go to another page. You can see my updated information in my question

Answer (score 0):

You need an navigation controller embedded i.e  add an navigation controller and set it as initial view controller and set the login view controller as root view controller for navigation controller , then upon successful credential check you can push to the other view controller as below

```
    - (IBAction)okPressed:(id)sender {

    NSString *username = [_usernameTextField text];
    NSString *password = [_passwordTextField text];

    if([username compare:@"andika"] && [password compare:@"1234"]) {
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Utama storyboard identifier" animated:YES];
//also remove login view from stack
[self removeFromParentViewController];
}
}
```

Comment: still can't go to another page. You can see my updated information in my question

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)okPressed:(id)sender
{

  NSString *username = [_usernameTextField text];
  NSString *password = [_passwordTextField text];

  if ([username isEqualToString:@"andika"] == YES && [password isEqualToString:@"1234"] ==YES ) 
  {
      Utama *NextView = [[Utama alloc]initWithNibName:@"Utama" bundle:nil];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:NextView animated:YES];
  }
```

}

Comment: still can't. I don't know :(